# c# lambda with inner variable for pre-calculation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, func

I have an entity framework application with a filtering lambda expression that looks like this:

`x => x.Where(pn => pn.Product.Evaluation.Any(ee => ee.EvaluationToDocuments.Any(e2d => e2d.Document.SpiderFailedCheckCount != null)))`

This turns out to be very slow, it would be much faster to go the other way, i.e. find the right EvaluationToDocuments, and select their products via the evaluations.

So I did a pre-calculation: 
`spiderFailedCheckCountProductIds = _context.EvaluationToDocuments.Where(e2d => e2d.Document.SpiderFailedCheckCount != null).Select(e2d => e2d.Evaluation.ProductID).Distinct().OrderBy(p => p).ToList();`

and then my first expression can be done like this instead:
`x => x.Where(pn => spiderFailedCheckCountProductIds.Contains(pn.ProductID))`

It could probably be even faster, but this is fast enough and many magnitudes faster than the first version.

Generally speaking, the purpose of local variables in a function is to avoid doing expensive calculations more than once. Can this be done in a lambda expression? Something like `(x) => var a = x+5, a*4`  (not the best example)

I would like to avoid writing ordinary functions, and keep these filtering functions as objects.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [let clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) (example from the MSDN):

```
var earlyBirdQuery =
    from sentence in strings
    let words = sentence.Split(' ')
    from word in words
    let w = word.ToLower()
    where w[0] == 'a' || w[0] == 'e'
        || w[0] == 'i' || w[0] == 'o'
        || w[0] == 'u'
    select word;
```

But note that your problem was another: the SQL query plan that was generated by your query was terrible. You solved this by doing two separate queries to the SQL.. Perhaps you can even merge the two queries together and do them in a single "batch".

SQL Server in general already caches equal sub-expressions. If you do twice the MAX(something) in your query, the SQL won't probably execute it twice. It will note that it can reuse the result and reuse it.

```
SELECT MAX(id), MAX(id) FROM Foo
```

or if you do

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1, 5) FROM Foo WHERE SUBSTRING(name, 1, 5) = 'Hello'
```

probably the `SUBSTRING` is built only once for each row.

Comment: Well it seems that in this case, SQL Server didn't catch the equal sub-expression. Do you have a suggestion for a better way of writing my lambda expression? I managed to change it to a multi-line expression which is similar to your let clause way, but it's still a two-stage rocket so to speak.